# Can I make an non-email app behave like an email-client when sending a message to another service?

Tags: email, protocols

I have been trying to research the email protocols which lay down a procedure for emails (data) to exchange between two users. There is a whole lot of defined rules w.r.t to how emails are processed, how spammers are identified and how an email sender is identified.

But the question that I have is: Can I make my non-email app seem like a mail-server to another mail-server? My app is another type of user-user messaging system, which does not require so much hard-coded user addresses within itself.

I can share the link to my app, if (first) asking this question itself is valid or not.

- Arvind.

Comment: Yeah, I could pick up coding to that level. Thanks.